# Need help pinpointing the CSS causing this alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with this new theme I tried out with OpenCart. I've tried my best to diagnose the issue using Firebug in Firefox, but I cannot pinpoint whats the culprit here.

**The problem can be seen [here](http://bit.ly/13KG6dz):**

http://bit.ly/13KG6dz

(Using bit.ly because IP address are not allowed - don't worry its not a virus)

Basically in OpenCart, you can add 'Options' to your Products. OpenCart comes with some sample dummy Products. One of these Products has 9 different Options, and all of them display fine. But when I define a new Option in OpenCart, and add it to this Product, there are alignment issues, which can be seen below:

***Pictured Example:***

**1) Initial Status:**

Default Options only. Everything is fine, no alignment issues.

[image]

**2) After adding a new Option:**

Now I define a new Option and add it to this Product, and the alignment issues are visible:

[image]

Note that is ONLY happens when I add a new Option to an existing sample product. However, this also ONLY happens on the particular theme being used on this OpenCart installation.

If anyone can get to the bottom of this, I'll be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES, as I guessed it, it was an issue of floats, add this line here

```
 <input type="radio" id="option-value-20" value="20" name="option[228]">
 <label for="option-value-20">No</label>
 <br>
 </div>
 <div style="clear: both"></div>
           <!-- ^This will clear your floats, alternatively you can use
                  overflow: hidden; on container element -->
```

Right after this `<div id="option-228" class="option boss_radio">` ends

Comment: Problem is the HTML is server generated. I cannot directly modify that I think. Can this not be changed in CSS or something ?

Comment: Yes it can, have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Ahmad Remove `float: left` from line 977 in `stylesheet.css`

Comment: I don't see anything relevant on that line. Did you mean line 1563 instead ? If thats the case then have a look at the comment I typed in for Zim84's answer ..

Comment: @Ahmad From this selector `.product-info .option.boss_radio`

Comment: Yep thats the one I was talking about too. Deleting that line creates another problem though. The label for the text field (4th Option from top) is now appearing way above the text field itself. Have a look at this picture: i.imgur.com/LX4Jy0y.png

Comment: @Ahmad Use `overflow: hidden;` in `.product-info .options`

Comment: Nice ! Seems to have solved my problem ! :D Thanks ! I'll mark your answer is being correct about 5-10 minutes, after I've done some additional tests. Can you tell me what `overflow: hidden` does ?

Comment: @Ahmad It will clear your floating elements :) and am going offline, this will solve it though, am sure

Comment: Actually problem is still not 100% solved. I added some more options the Product, and this is the result: http://i.imgur.com/xqL7kCr.png. The Yes/No options for `Include Addon C` option are not visible entirely, and the label for `Select Packaging Type` option is place above the text field itself ..

Comment: Ignore the thing about the `Include Addon C` option in above picture. I managed to fix that. It was an Option configuration issue.

Comment: Marking this as the answer as this did technically solve the original problem. For this new problem, I've created another thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493856/label-and-text-field-not-aligned-together

Answer (score 0):

You have float defined in your css rule `boss_radio`. If you remove this class your elements are aligned fine! The problem is, that this rule makes the element float with a width of just around 30%, which will let other elements stay on the same line.

Comment: Well that fixes *this* issue, but it creates another. The label for the text field (4th Option from top) is now appearing way above the text field itself. Have a look at this picture: http://i.imgur.com/LX4Jy0y.png

Comment: I see, can you remove the class `boss_radio`?

Comment: If I delete it (tested by deleting the rule in Firebug), the end result is still the same as that in i.imgur.com/LX4Jy0y.png. So unfortunately deleting the rule doesn't solve the problem for me.

Comment: No, don't delete the rule but delete the class `boss_radio` from your `div` element: `<div class="option boss_radio">`. Can you do that? Are you even doing html by yourself or are you _just_ clicking a wizard in your admin tool?

Comment: The HTML pages are generated by OpenCart itself. I just define the Products, Options in the admin section of OpenCart. Thus, I cannot change the HTML as that is out of my hands. However I can change the CSS. So can I somehow repair this by only changing the CSS ?

Comment: What part of the css can you change? the sourcefiles directly? only some rules that get applied? Can you configure your option in a different way, so that no class with a rule `float` gets used?

Comment: I can change the CSS files that are being imported into the HTML of this page, at the top. Those CSS files I can change in anyway needed. The admin area does not allow functionality to configure CSS for Options from there, if that's what you meant.