# Label and text field not aligned together?

Tags: html, css, opencart

I have yet another alignment issue that needs to be solved. I'm no CSS expert, so I need the experts' help. I have tried playing around in Firebug but I couldn't figure it out.

**Site where this issue is present:** http://bit.ly/13KG6dz

(Using bit.ly because IP addresses are not allowed - don't worry its not a virus)

Note that I ***CAN*** change any CSS file being called in this page, but I ***CANNOT*** change the HTML code of the page itself, because the HTML code is server generated.

**The issue is this:**

Shown in red in the picture below:

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You should float it like the rest of fields in the group

```
#option-231{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will be a good solution, because this CSS rule will ONLY apply for option 231's ... 231 is a server generated number, and it will change if I remove 2-3 other Options from this product, meaning that this CSS rule will not longer work. So I need a more generalized solution.

Comment: @Ahmad then find a better way to select the element.

Answer (score 0):

label is basically block element.
use any css display property for desired result.
like

```
.classNameOfLabel {
     display: inline
 }
```